# Find the number of rows in SQLite Table on Windows Phone

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, sqlite-net

New to programming apps for the Windows Phone and to using SQLite. I am currently using the newest SQLite, with the SQLite-net api, and creating an application for the windows phone 8.

I can see from various tutorials how to add data entries to the SQLite Table and how to delete entries. I can also see that there is a way to automatically iterate the identifier of the Table Rows. So my question has 2 parts:

First, is the identifier an integer that just adds +1 for each new row? And Second, how can I find the total number of rows in the SQLite Table.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I don't have an answer for Windows Phone 8, but I do have one for Windows 10 UWP. Well, partially. I'll start with the second part of your question.

```
using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
{
    int count = dbConn.Query<Assessment>("select * from Assessment").Count;
    return count;
}
```

As far as I know, when you add a new row to a sqlite table without specifying the identifier explicitly, it automatically increments the identifier of the table and inserts it along with the rest of the columns.

Comment: interesting, thanks! Actually, I have a per-requisite to this question. How do you create an SQL lite database on the windows phone? I was never quite able to create this database.